# At least one of the filed is required validation in Angular 11 reactive form

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms, angular11

I am using Angular 11 reactive form with below 7 fields.

- Start Date (Mandatory)
- End Date (Mandatory)

At least one field is filled

- phone Number
- address
- author
- user ID
- company

My form should be valid only if **start** and **end** date are selected and among other five fields, at least one field is filled. How can I put this custom validator in my reactive form?
Below is my typescript form component.

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      startDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      endDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    phoneNumber: new FormControl(''),
     address: new FormControl(''),
    author: new FormControl(),
     userID: new FormControl(''),
      company: new FormControl('')
     
    }, { validators: dateValidator }

    );
```

Comment: Did you write the custom validator function? If so, you just need to add it to the `validators` array like this: `{ validators: [dateValidator, customValidator] }`

Comment: @lbsn No, I have not written the custom validator function yet. Yes,  I will include the custom validator in the validators array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic example of how you're custom validator might look like:

```
export const atLeastOneValidator = (keys: string[]) => {
  return (group: FormGroup) => {
    const { controls } = group;
    return keys.some(key => controls[key] && !!controls[key].value)
      ? null
      : { atLeastOne: 'error' };
  };
};
```

And here's how you could use it:

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        startDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        endDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        phoneNumber: new FormControl(''),
        address: new FormControl(''),
        author: new FormControl(),
        userID: new FormControl(''),
        company: new FormControl('')
      },
      { validators: dateValidator, atLeastOneValidator(['phoneNumber', 'address', 'author', 'userID', 'company']) }
    );
```

Comment: @Ibsn Thanks for your response. I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. May be I am making some mistake since I am new to Angular. Anyways I have found a solution. Please check my answer too. It is working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code to solve the problem.

```
this.myForm = new FormGroup(
      {
        startDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        endDate: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        phoneNumber: new FormControl(''),
        address: new FormControl(''),
        author: new FormControl(),
        userID: new FormControl(''),
        company: new FormControl('')
      },
      { validators: [dateValidator, atLeastOneValidator] }
    );
```

Validator function :

```
export const atLeastOneValidator :ValidatorFn=(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null  => {
    
      if((control.get('phoneNumber')?.value!='')||(control.get('address')?.value!='')
      ||(control.get('author')?.value!='')||(control.get('userID')?.value!='')
      ||(control.get('company')?.value!='')){
        return null;
      }
      else{
        return {atLeastone : 'error'};
      }
     
      
        
   
  };
```